# wordpress theme not importing correctly from local to online

Tags: wordpress

Hi I am currently developing an Wordpress site offline on local server and want to upload to my domain online. I don't need to transfer the database, but I would like my pages, theme, widgets to work correctly.
What I am doing:

- Copying Wordpress directory to domain directory through ftp.
- Exporting everything in local server Wordpress and importing in
  online Wordpress.

All my pages/posts are transferred, and my theme is installed but not set default.  When I select it, everything is set to the themes original defaults, not like changed on the local server (for example tagline, background, etc). Also the widgets are the default settings.

Am I doing something wrong?
I am using Wordpress 3.4.2
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have just forgotten that some options for your themes are actually stored as WordPress options, so if you don't upload your database, you will not transfer these settings.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a tutorial explaining step-by-step how to transfer a WordPress site to another server: http://www.sebastianbroways.com/wordpress-transfer/

If you follow each step the site should retain all the settings, including the template preferences. Good luck.